# Join by user_id in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

How to choose the data by symfony two tables. For example there is a table of posts, it is a field user_id (the user who created the post), I do select all posts and passed to the template. The template must display the user data from the table users (for each post on your user_id) as this can be done?

I read the documentation but did not really understand

My query now:

```
   public function indexAction()
    {
        $posts = $this->getDoctrine()
                      ->getRepository('AcmePostBundle:Post');

        $queryPosts = $posts->createQueryBuilder('p')
                       ->orderBy('p.id', 'DESC')
                       ->getQuery();

        return new Response(var_dump($queryPosts->getResult()));
   }
```

I wanna get column `path` of  table 'users' by user_id

Answer (score 0):

Did you try , in your template, to do :
( let's say you return posts from our controller )

```
{% for post in posts %}
    {{ post.user }}
{% endfor %}
```

Doctrine load the whole thing by itself, you should see that in your var_dump

---

Try this in your repository post

```
public function myInnerJoin()
{

       $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('f') 
            ->select('f','g')
            ->innerJoin('f.user', 'g'); 

       return $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
}
```

and in controller

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('AcmeBundle:..');
$result = $repository->myInnerJoin();
```

Comment: no, user of $posts missing. I didn't make join, I do not know how to do it

Comment: i added an example of how to do a join. you can also leftjoin,according to your needs